# Share Android device keyboard to android based jellybean projector Browser

Tags: android, keyboard, share

I have an Android device, which I want to connect to the Android-based projector with Jellybean installed into the projector. What I want is to share Android device keyboard to the Android projector virtually, how this can be achieved so that my Android device keyboard is connected to Android projector and text can be written to Android projector browser. Projector has native browser-based Android app for browsing the internet.

I search on the internet but didn’t get any solution, therefore I am here to get help from you guys. A small help you yours can also lead to the solution to my problem.